# Structure to store, display, sort, search, save, delete data in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, structure

I created a structure in C++. It stores information about Movies like Movie name, Movie ID, Movie genre etc.
Now I have to use switch case to 1) Enter information 2) Display Information 3) Search information 4) Sort movie information 5) Delete information 6) Save 7) Exit.
Now if I choose option 1 and enter information. How it will display options menu for displaying information. And again show options menu for sorting.....
**code so for**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Movies
{
int id;
char name[50];
int ranking;
char genre[10];
int business;
};

int main() 
{
struct Movies mov[5];
int i, opt;

cout << "Press 1 to Enter movie information" << endl;
cout << "Press 2 to Display movie information" << endl;
cout << "Press 3 to Search movie" << endl;
cout << "Press 4 to Sort movie information" << endl;
cout << "Press 5 to Delete" << endl;
cout << "Press 6 to Save movie information to file" << endl;
cout << "Press 7 to Exit the program" << endl << endl;
cin >> opt;

switch (opt)
{
    case 1:
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Movie " << i+1 << " Information " << endl;
            cout << "Enter ID: ";
            cin >> mov[i].id;
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            cin >> mov[i].name;
            cout << "Enter ranking: ";
            cin >> mov[i].ranking;
            cout << "Enter genre: ";
            cin >> mov[i].genre;
            cout << "Enter Business: ";
            cin >> mov[i].business;
            cout << endl;
        }
    break;

    case 2:
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Displaying Movie " << i + 1 <<"Information"<< endl;
            cout << "ID: " << mov[i].id << endl;
            cout << "Name: " << mov[i].name << endl;
            cout << "Ranking: " << mov[i].ranking << endl;
            cout << "Genre: " << mov[i].genre << endl;
            cout << "Business: " << mov[i].business << endl;
            return 0;
        }

    case 3:

}
}
```

Comment: Put everything in a big `while (opt != 7)` loop. Initialize `opt` before the loop of course.

Comment: Only the switch case or the whole main?

Comment: All of main except the first two lines

Comment: thanks man, I will try it